# What are the great iPhone apps to discover new music?

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation, music

Back in the days I used [Last.fm](http://last.fm) suggestions  but they are way too generic and aren't useful to me anymore.  I switched to [RYM](http://rateyourmusic.com) and its recommendation engine is much nicer, however I'm also looking for some **iPhone apps** that would allow me to discover awesome new music on the go.

I'm looking for these features:

- an easy way to browse through artists and albums;
- a wide range of non-mainstream artists;
- a recommendation engine and/or a smart “similar artists” engine;
- track previews (at least 30 sec.);
- no limitations on total preview play count;
- no need to subscribe to any paid service;
- ideally, reviews for selected albums;
- some kind of bookmarking to store my findings.

I don't care for the price if the app meets my needs.
What does AppStore have to offer?

Please, post **one app per answer**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [SuperSonic](http://supersonicapp.com/) by [HunterMedia](http://huntedmedia.com/)

While the app doesn't let you directly browse artists and albums, it definitely uses a [terrific recommendation engine](http://the.echonest.com/) and lets you focus on finding the new music—by not standing in  your way and getting a bunch of recommended tracks based on a given artist seed.

Each preview lasts **for a whole minute** which I think is enough to form an opinion (and bookmark the track). Bookmarked tracks **can be re-listened** at any time (with the same time constraint). The buy icon link is small and non-obtrusive.

Out of ten tracks I have listened to, I loved eight and two of them were by my two other favorite bands that the app had no way of knowing.  I also came to like the “passive discovery” workflow where  I hear new music without having to browse through the bands and tap tap tap.

Last.fm radio was never even *close* to this.

**And SuperSonic is free**.

The last bit that got me was adjustable recommendations popularity, danceability, tempo and the ability to ignore these settings altogether.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not in any way affiliated with the app or recommendation engine (I even live in a different country). It's just that I got exactly what I needed, and even more.

Comment: A grain of salt: the app won't play music in the hold mode. I guess I can live with that though.

Answer (score 2):

[Discovr](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/discovr-music-discover-new/id412768094?mt=8) is a great app for this. You just enter the name of an artist, and then a list of related artists appear. A network graph appears with all of the artists. You can play previews, and watch videos. Pretty decent app.

Comment: Thanks! I checked it out and it is good. For some reason, however, I keep getting "No songs found for this artist" for any imaginable artist (may have to do with the country I live in). Still, the app is cool.

Answer (score 1):

It won't necessarily fulfill all your criteria, but Pandora is a great place to start. :)

Pandora syncs "radio stations" with pandora.com.  These stations are created based a specific type of music, music that sounds like a specific song or artist.  A certain amount of skips are allowed per hour, to find something you like in a particular station. After that point you must listen to what the station has or switch to another station.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it's unavailable in Russian App Store (as Pandora itself in Russia) so I can't check it out. But thanks for sharing, others might stumble upon this as well. Generally, we're trying to develop the community around this Q&A by writing definitive, full answers so it would be nice if you could expand yours with some overview of what's (not) in the app, maybe a link and a screenshot could help as well. Thanks!